# How to pass variable in a function call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my functional component I'm calling two functions, which are doing nearly the same thing:

```
const App = () => {
    const handleOnClickFirst = () => {
      setValue('first')
    }
    const handleOnClickSecond = () => {
      setValue('second')
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {anything === true
            ? <Button onClick={handleOnClickFirst} />
            : <Button onClick={handleOnClickSecond} />}
        </div>
    )
}
```

So there should be simply only

```
const handleOnClick = (value) => {
    setValue(value)
}
```

But how do I pass the value in `onClick`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we know with JSX you pass a function as the event handler. So we can wrap our handler with another function and call handler with arguments in this wrapper function

```
onClick={(event) => handleOnClick(value)}
```

or for old versions we can do

```
onClick={function(event){ handleOnClick(value) }}
```

If you don't need events you can just pass it like this

```
onClick={() => handleOnClick(value)}
```

Also if it is a Class base component we use bind to pass method context and arguments

```
class App extends React.Component {
  handleOnClick(val) {
    console.log(`${val}`);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleOnClick.bind(this, "test")}>
        click me
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So `onclick={handleOnClick}` and `onClick={() => handleOnClick()}` are the same, if no parameter is needed?

Comment: `bind` is no longer relevant in this context and arrow functions can be used for both the class method and for the inline callbacks.

Comment: @user3142695 it's the same if `handleOnClick` takes no parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
<button onClick={(event)=>handleOnClick(<pass your paramter here>)}></button>
```

Comment: where would the event be?

Comment: I edited the answer , is that what you meant? or you are referring to some other event?

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
 onClick={() => handleOnClick(value)}
```

edit:

More information here: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
const App = () => {
     const handleOnClick = (passedInValue) => {
          setValue(passedInValue)
     }
     return (
          <div>
               {anything === true
               ? <Button onClick={() => handleOnClick("first")} />
               : <Button onClick={() => handleOnClick("second")} />}
          </div>
      )
    }
```